# hide/show placeholder in jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble hiding and showing the placeholder in .sortable of jQuery.
Please see  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phloks/9z81pmba/3/)

(Please disregard the layout. On my live site it looks better...)

(Also, please notice, the first dropzone has been disabled..)

What I want is to disable the placeholder in the dropzones (the 8 on the right) when the maximum number of 4 drops has been reached.
I can drag and drop both ways, and I did manage to disable the display of the placeholder on the righthand sides when the max of 4 drops was reached.
However, I suspect that my code prevents the placeholder to be shown at all in the origin zone, because there are more than 4 elements in the origin zone.

I tried working around this by using an extra variable to determine where I am when dragging/dropping, like this :

```
var item = $(ui.item);
var from = item.parent().is("#draggable");
```

and then using an if/else if/else construction to be able to detect where I am, and thus decide wether to hide or show the placeholder.

Can't get it to work....

So, the goal is that placeholders should always be shown, except when in the dropzones on the right the maximum number of 4 drops has occurred.

Anyone know if I'm on the right track here ?

Comment: `$(placeholders).toggle()` has built in the functionality that you want - show and hide the element without the need to `if`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out (almost!)

For future reference: Had to use the `over:` function of `.sortable`, and had to build in some if then else logic.

Now I always see the placeholder in the left pane, and the placeholder is no longer shown when the right panes have 4 children, while still showing the placeholder when dragging/dropping within one of the panes on the right. However, one small issue remains: when I drag/drop from one pane on the right to another one on the right, and the panes are "full", the placeholder still appears. Must do some more checking, I guess...

FWIW: Please see the finished product at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phloks/9z81pmba/8/)